# Single SQL query on many to many relationship using join

Tags: sql

I have a simple database with few tables (and some sample columns)

**Employee (ID, Title, Content)**

**Project (ID, Title)**

**ProjectEmployee(ID ,EMPLOYEE_ID,PROJECT_ID)**

Need to find employee's whose don't have any project using join query

I am able to do it using subquery

```
select * from employee 
where id not in (select  id from project_employee);
```

Comment: `NOT IN` is a bit tricky if the subquery returns null values. Consider `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `LEFT JOIN` with `NOT NULL` give you the expected results.

```
select e.* 
from employee e
LEFT JOIN project_employee pe on pe.id = e.id
where pe.id is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be best implemented using `not exists`, joining is not the correct solution if you do not need to return any columns from the joined table.

```
select *
from employee e
where not exists (select * from project_employee pe where pe.id = e.id)
```